# Does method overloading implicitly typecasts to larger type even though compatible type is available

Tags: java, methods, overriding

When I execute below program since child class has compatible methods call should have gone to child class but instead parent class methods are called. Is there any rule in overloading which is causing this behaviour ?

```
public class OverrideTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent d=new Child();

    d.test(10);

    d.add(1,2,3);        
   }
}


class Parent{

void test(double d) {
    System.out.println("Value of D:"+ d);
}

    public void add(double a, double b, double c){               
        double sum = a+b+c; 
        System.out.println("sum Double:"+ sum);

    } 
}

class Child extends Parent{

  void test(int i) {
    System.out.println("i:"+ i);
}

public void add(int a, int b, int c){          
        int sum = a+b+c; 
        System.out.println("sum Int:"+ sum);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to invoke is chosen at compile time. The compiler only considers methods which exist on the type of the variable, i.e. `Parent`, because all it knows is that `d` is a `Parent`.

Since it only knows about `test(double)` and `add(double,double,double)`, these are the methods which will be invoked. Because they are not overridden in the child class (only overloaded), the methods from the parent class are invoked.

The compiler automatically widens the `int` parameters to double to make them compatible with the method's formal parameter types.

The fact that `d` is more specifically a `Child` at runtime is not used.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.Really helpful.Suppose if we keep both parent class and child class methods in single class then it would call int type methods.